# Cast text to timestamp

Tags: r, timestamp

Let's say if I have the following data frame.

```
date <- c('23/01/21 22:53','15/02/21 20:01', '05/03/21 07:49', '10/01/21 18:15', '09/03/21 12:53' )
id <- c(1:5)
df <- data_frame(id, date)
```

I tried to cast this from text to timestamp using the following code

```
df$date2 <- strptime(df$date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

This is the result that I get

[image]

The year is now showing 0021 instead of 2021. Is there a way I can show the right year?
Much appreciated with any help.

Comment: `strptime(df$date, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")`, since you only have two digits year.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a replacement to convert the two digit year to the correct four digit value:

```
date <- c('23/01/21 22:53','15/02/21 20:01', '05/03/21 07:49', '10/01/21 18:15', '09/03/21 12:53')
date <- paste0(substr(date, 1, 6),
               ifelse(as.numeric(substr(date, 7, 8)) < 30, "20", "19"),
               substr(date, 7, 14))
df <- data.frame(c(1:5), date)

df$date2 <- strptime(df$date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```